# Varnish causes user to log off right after the login

Tags: php, apache, magento2, varnish, varnish-4

We setup two web servers with Apache 2.4, php 7.0.32 and Magento 2.1 with Varnish 4.x version and one MySQL database, Apache is listening on port 8080 and Varnish on port 80, web servers are able to cache web pages, but if a user logs in and clicks on any link on the page, he gets logged out, maybe it's related to the session storage.

I'm a beginner in Magento and all this stuff, can someone please guide me in the right direction, something I overlooked, would really appreciate.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Magento provided VCL? It looks like Varnish is overcaching (which shouldn't happen in the default configuration). Try to have a look at `varnishlog` while logging it, it will show you all the transaction, if they are HIT, MISS or PASS. My guess is that you need to tell varnish to pass for some pages related to logging in